# Unreal Rig Issue Control Rig - Hierarchy discrepancy for bone 'pelvis' - different parents on Control Rig vs SkeletalMesh

Tags: character, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I created a character in Daz Studio. Then using the Daz to Unreal plugin, the character was exported to Unreal. I tried both the pluging and plain FBX export. The character is successfully imported in Unreal, but the bone setup is what gives issue. the animations from Unreal do not play well and act strange. I observed that Daz Bone rig has one extra bone which is "Shoulder" there is a Uper shoulder which is placed on the ollar and the usual shoulder. Please if any one has any solution help

While Importing i also get these 2 warnings

Control Rig  - Hierarchy discrepancy for bone 'pelvis' - different parents on Control Rig vs SkeletalMesh.

Control Rig  - Hierarchy discrepancy for bone 'head' - different parents on Control Rig vs SkeletalMesh.

Expecting the default animations to work good and/or the to match the bone setup